# What is the regular expression for a Spanish word?

Tags: .net, regex, cpu-word

Regular expression languages use \B to include A..Z, a..z, 0..9, and _, and \b is defined as a word boundary.

How can I write a regular expression that matches all valid Spanish words, including characters such as: á, í, ó, é, ñ, etc.?

I'm using .NET.

Answer (score 6):

Use a Spanish locale and make your regex locale-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

This depends heavily on the language (and regex engine) you're using.

In Perl, `\w` matches all word characters, regardless of language or alphabet, and something like `/\b(\w+)\b/` would (probably) match Spanish words as well as English words or Russian words.

In languages using PCRE, `\w` (and therefore probably `\b`) do NOT match Unicode characters. You will probably need to build your own set. I suggest something like `[\wáéíóúñ]` (matches all word characters, plus the accented characters you want), and the PCRE library has to be pre-built with Unicode support before this will even work.

If you're using something else, good luck. Some regex engines don't even support Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex system should have something equivalent to Python's `re.L` (aka `re.LOCALE`) to make a regex locale-dependent, so that what's a word-character and what isn't changes with locale, as do "word boundaries" etc.  Are you instead asking for a way to compensate for some given regex system *not* supporting locale, trying to force the issue anyway...?