# Regex matching letter characters

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I've this regex:

```
if (cadena.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]+$")) return true;
```

It's accepting from A to Z as lowercase and uppercase. Also accepting spaces.

But this is working just for english. For instance, in Catalan we've the 'ç' character. Also we've characters with 'á', or 'à', etc.

Did some google and I couldn't find any way to do this.

I found out that I can filter for UTF-8 but this would accept characters that are not really a letter.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Take a look at [Unicode blocks](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/gstarted.html#appendix-c).

Comment: Dunno if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896374/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-a-spanish-word more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548815/how-do-i-match-latin-unicode-characters-in-coldfusion-or-java-regex?rq=1

Comment: Also have a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/9499851/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499851/regex-for-validating-alphabetics-and-numbers-in-the-localized-string/9500409#9500409)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
[\p{L}\s]+
```

`\p{L}` means any Unicode letter.

[fiddle.re Demo](http://fiddle.re/9q096).

Comment: Doesn't this match non-Latin characters as well, which is not exactly what the OP was looking for (even though they did accept this answer)? It matches `안녕`, for example. It seems like `\p{IsLatin}` is a better fit if you specifically want to match Latin characters ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

Comment: @NickChammas: op explicitly wanted any Unicode letters matched.

Comment: At this point 3 years after the fact I suppose it's a moot point  but the OP's title and intended use case of matching the Catalan alphabet suggest they want to just match Latin characters and not all Unicode (which would include other alphabets, like Korean). I don't see where the OP explicitly wanted to match "any Unicode letter". But anyway, I upvoted this answer because it was helpful. I hope my earlier comment helps others who, like me, came to this page looking for a way to match just Latin characters and not any Unicode.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, in case this is a point of confusion, Latin != ASCII. Most Latin characters, like `ë`, `ɶ`, or `ṧ`, can only be [represented by Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode). `\p{IsLatin}` will match those characters without matching characters from other, non-Latin alphabets.

Comment: best solution 

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and use a class (e.g. `\p{InLATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT}`).

Comment: This documentation page does NOT have `Latin1Supplemental` mentioned anywhere. Even googling for `Latin1Supplemental` at `site:oracle.com` does not find it. What gives?

Comment: It could be named something different. Please check the documentation for `Character.UnicodeBlock`. There is a constant named `LATIN_!_SUPPLEMENTAL` which name could be used for the `\p{}` name.

Comment: This should be: `Pattern.compile("\\p{InLATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT}")`. Mind the `In` preceding the `Character.UnicodeBlock` constant. From "Mastering Regular Expressions": "Unicode blocks are supported, requiring an ‘In’ prefix."

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker You are right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @UwePlonus Sorry, that still doesn't compile. It should be either `\p{InLATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT}`, `\p{InLATIN-1 SUPPLEMENT}` or `\p{InLATIN-1SUPPLEMENT}` as per the `idName` and `aliases` taken from `Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT`.