# French regex that supports only text type

Tags: regex, bean-validation

i want help in finding a french Regex that support only caracters, spaces and french acute like é,è,à,ò ...

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980870/regex-with-latin-characters

Comment: A French letter regex from the dupe - `[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]`. Just add a whitespace (`\s`) and add the quantifier at the end: `*` (to match 0 or more occurrences) or `+` (to match 1 or more occurrences).