# Google Spreadsheets Regex - Separating first name with latin characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, unicode, google-sheets-formula

I have a column in Google Spreadsheets that have full names. It looks like this:

```
Full_name
Acacio Bernardo
Carlos Moraes
André da Silva
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
Full_name           First_name
Acacio Bernardo     Acacio
Carlos Moraes       Carlos
André da Silva      André
```

I'm using the following:

```
=regexextract(B1;"\w*")
```

It works fine for the first two names ("Acacio" and "Carlos"), however in the third one instead of "André" I'm getting "Andr". I noticed that this regex expression doesn't work with accents and latin characters.

I tried to apply the regex in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980870/regex-with-latin-characters) however seems that google spreadsheets doesn't support it (I get straight to an error, couldn't even explore it a little further).

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want to write google-apps-script or simply use a function in spreadsheet?

Comment: Simply use a function in spreadsheet. I've put the wrong tag by mistake, I will fix that now. Thanks for bringing it @RiyafaAbdulHameed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\S` (non-space characters class) instead of `\w`:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\S+")
```

Result:

[image]